# Find out deadlock reason

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

We have NUnit project witn tests and many cases for each test. All of them run in parallel mode.
I found 2 deadlock reasons. 1 - is table, but second one - no name or some id.

How to find this object?

just for reference We have gybrid mode in app ef context + dapper for difficult sql

[image]

Comment: Open the .xdl in [Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/new-deadlock-visualizations-in-sql-sentry-and-plan-explorer), it might give a little more detail (however if Dapper is sending 500 lines of spaghetti, the .xdl is never going to store all of it).

Comment: Good tool. Why sql profile doesn't show while plan explorer shows tables names?

Comment: Because profiler was written 25 years ago and [you shouldn't be using it](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/03/sql-performance/deprecated-features-2)? Lots of vendors build software to fill gaps left by Microsoft.

Comment: yes, but if microsoft will make some kind plan explorer in next version of sql then it will be problem with sales)

Comment: Seems quite speculative, and since they haven't done it for 25 years, I don't think fear of lost sales as a result has been a major concern.

Comment: Software companies are quite complex, they make choices about what to build and what not to build based on a lot more than "someone wants it." Since an external vendor built a (free!) tool that performs this functionality, and there is a neverending list of work to do, why would Microsoft waste time on something that the market already provides for free? Especially in Profiler, which has been dormant and deprecated for years? What evidence do you have that doing so would increase sales (or not doing so would cost sales)? You should talk to Microsoft, since your peers can't solve this issue.

Comment: Plan explorer is free? I didn't check but I thought it is not. I have one example. I think you know Jetbrains company. They developed Resharper tool which was ver popular even not free but then Microsoft made many things from resharper in next version of Visual studio. I think it was done to sale visual studio. Maybe same can be done for mssql

Answer (score 2):

Extract the XML of the deadlock graph and use the script I give to you to extract SQL text to undrerstand what's happening...

DECLARE @XML XML = N'??? my deadlock XML !!!';

```
WITH
TX AS
(
SELECT @XML AS TextData
),
TVM AS
(
SELECT v.value('(./inputbuf)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Query,
       i.value('(./deadlock/@victim)[1]','varchar(32)') AS ProcessVictim,
       v.value('(./@id)[1]','varchar(32)') AS ProcessID
FROM  TX
      CROSS APPLY TextData.nodes('/deadlock-list') AS X(i)
      CROSS APPLY TextData.nodes('/deadlock-list/deadlock/process-list/process') AS V(v)
),
TVV AS
(
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) AS ID,
       Query,
       CASE WHEN ProcessVictim = ProcessID THEN 'Victim!' ELSE 'Alive' END AS FinalState
FROM TVM
),
TQV AS
(
SELECT ID, Query
FROM   TVV
WHERE  FinalState = 'Victim!'
)
SELECT TVV.ID, TVV.Query,
       CASE WHEN TQV.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Victim!' ELSE 'Alive' END AS FinalState
FROM   TVV
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TQV
             ON TVV.ID = TQV.ID AND TVV.Query = TQV.Query
ORDER BY 1;
```

The result will be like this :

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I can see now 2 conflicted dapper sqls each 500+ lines. 1. Is it possible to see exact statement? 2. StartTime is important in your sql? When I compile  I get error "no such field" I changed a little your sql to SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ProcessVictim) AS ID,

Comment: StratTime is when you capture this information via SQL Profiler